# Как работает оператор break с меткой?

Tags: java

Вот смотрю пример кода и нашел тут вот такое

```
public static List<Word> detectAllWords(int[][] crossword, String... words) {
    List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    int[][] searchDirections = new int[][] {
        {0, 1},
        {1, 1},
        {1, 0},
        {1, -1},
        {0, -1},
        {-1, -1},
        {-1, 0},
        {-1, 1},
    };
    for (String word : words) nextWord:{
        for (int i = 0; i < crossword.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < crossword[i].length; j++) {
                if (word.charAt(0) == crossword[i][j])
                    for (int directions = 0; directions < searchDirections.length; directions++) {
                        int     tmp_i = i,
                            tmp_j = j,
                            wordPos = 1;
                        while (wordPos < word.length()) {
                            tmp_i += searchDirections[directions][0];
                            tmp_j += searchDirections[directions][1];
                            if (tmp_i < 0 || tmp_i >= crossword.length || tmp_j < 0 || tmp_j >= crossword[tmp_i].length)
                                break;
                            if (word.charAt(wordPos) != crossword[tmp_i][tmp_j])
                                break;
                            else if (wordPos == word.length() - 1) {
                                Word tWord = new Word(word);
                                tWord.setStartPoint(j, i);
                                tWord.setEndPoint(tmp_j, tmp_i);
                                wordList.add(tWord);
                                break nextWord;
                            }
                            wordPos++;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return wordList;
}
```

Так вот первый раз вижу вот такое условие

```
for (String word : words) nextWord:{
```

и потом это как то привязано к строке ниже

```
break nextWord;
```

подскажите как это работает или где есть что почитать?

Comment: Просто переход [по метке](http://info.javarush.ru/javarush_articles/2015/12/03/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0.html). Использовать строго не рекомендуется.

Comment: а чем затрудняет использование кода?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это оператор `break` с меткой. В случае его срабатывания происходит переход к коду, который находится за блоком кода с заданной меткой.

Его удобно использовать для выхода из вложенных циклов. Оператор `break` без метки позволяет перейти только на один уровень вверх, а с помощью `break label` можно сразу выйти из цикла любой вложенности.

Здесь он используется для выхода из вложенного цикла (из 5-го уровня происходит переход сразу к циклу первого уровня).

Прочитать можно в любом пособии по Java.

Простой пример:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        label: for (int i=0; i<4; i++)  {
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
                if (i == 2 && j == 3) {
                    break label;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
i = 0, j = 0
i = 0, j = 1
i = 0, j = 2
i = 0, j = 3
i = 1, j = 0
i = 1, j = 1
i = 1, j = 2
i = 1, j = 3
i = 2, j = 0
i = 2, j = 1
i = 2, j = 2
i = 2, j = 3
End
```

PS. `break label` следует использовать только при крайней необходимости, так как он затрудняет восприятие кода.