# Вложенные циклы for БЕЗ скобок

Tags: java

```
for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
  for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) 
     if (i==0 & j==0) break;
```

В этом случае программа выйдет из обоих циклов или только из внутреннего?

UPDATED
  Нужный результат достигается только с использованием скобок:

```
 for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
      for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++){ 
         if (i==0 & j==0) break;
}
if (i==0 & j==0) break;
}
```

Comment: А проверить самостоятельно никак не получается?

Comment: [Вместо тысячи слов](http://tpcg.io/tHmUrn).

Comment: можно использовать [метку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620657)

Comment: Это тривиальный вопрос, а метка его усложняет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хоть со скобками, хоть без, оператор `break` осуществляет выход только из внутреннего цикла.

Comment: Cоответственно i=0 и j=0 я не получаю при таком коде?